# Adding custom language to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, localization

I would like to use SQL Server `@@langid` variable to return different data based on current connection language (set in connection string or with `SET LANGUAGE`). This works perfectly well for built-in languages, but there are just 34 of them and I'd like to make sure this technique is extensible.

As far as I understand, languages are stored in `syslanguages` table. Is there a way to add custom language to running SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't add custom languages to the SQL Server system.

An end user won't interact with the system as such: you'd implement multi-language within your database design/application. The system language is irrelevant.

Comment: "you can't add custom languages to the SQL Server system" - do you have any references for this statement please?

Comment: No, because documentation only tells you what you *can* do usually.